# flask_login.login_user giving error when an user object is passed to it

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

My Code is continuously showing :

```
TypeError: login_user() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

But in the [flask documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#login-example)  it clearly accepts an object as its parameter.

My Login Code:

```
@app.route('/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
def login_user():
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        attemptedUser=User.query.filter_by(uusername=form.username.data).first()
        attemptedPassword=form.password.data
        if attemptedUser and attemptedUser.comparePassword(attemptedPassword=form.password.data):
            login_user(attemptedUser)
            return redirect(url_for("index"))
        else:
            return "password not correct"
    if request.method=='GET':
        return render_template("login.html",form=form)
```

And i am also doubtful whether giving it **attemptedUser obj** or **username associated** *with that attemptedUser* can make a difference or it will work the same?

My Models.py file:

```
from market import db ,login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class User(db.Model,UserMixin):
    uid=db.Column(db.Integer(),primary_key=True)
    uusername=db.Column(db.String(30),nullable=False,unique=True)
    upassword =db.Column(db.String(30),nullable=False,unique=True)
    uaddress= db.Column(db.String(30))
    uphone=db.Column(db.Integer(),nullable=False,unique=True)

    # def __repr__(self):
    #     return f'{self.uusername}'
    
    @property 
    def password(self):
        return self.password

    def comparePassword(self,attemptedPassword):
        return attemptedPassword==self.upassword
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've imported `login_user` in code not shown above,

```
def login_user():
```

is masking it. When the code later does

```
login_user(attemptedUser)
```

it's getting your function, not one from `flask_login`. Rename your function.